# Merge two arrays with unequal values into key value pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that are basically HTML table data.  I want to merge them into one.  One of the arrays, `$headers`, will always be a smaller number than the second array `$data`.

For example:

```
$headers = array("Name","Phone","E-Mail");
$data = array("Bob", "Phone1", "E-Mail1", "Mike", "Phone2", "Email2", "Jim",  "Phone3", "E-Mail3");
```

What I want is to somehow loop through these two arrays and merge them into one with a key value pair to end up with this:

```
$values[1][Name]       = "Bob";
$values[1][Phone]      = "Phone1";
$values[1][E-Mail]     = "E-Mail1";
$values[2][Name]       = "Mike";
$values[2][Phone]      = "Phone2";
$values[2][E-Mail]     = "E-Mail2";
$values[3][Name]       = "Jim";
$values[3][Phone]      = "Phone3";
$values[3][E-Mail]     = "E-Mail3";
```

Basically, split them into a multidimensional array that is sorted by row of the table.

Right now, storing my data differently is not an option.  My question is on how to extract it into this new array.

Comment: `array_combine` requires equal number of values in array.  I am looking at `array_chunk` now -- will get back to you on that...

Comment: The indexes really start at 1 rather than 0?

Comment: @Don'tPanic no.  Typo.  I removed that anyway, not needed for the question.

Comment: I don't think you want `[]` in each of the assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it, using `array_chunks` only:

```
$values = array_chunk($data, count($headers));
```

This almost produced what I wanted, except the key was the index from the headers array, not the header itself.  Since I still had I reference to the headers array, when I wanted to loop through, I did it like this:

When I wanted to use these values in the array, I extracted like this:

```
foreach ($values[$key] as $key => $value)
{
      $value; // the data
      $headers[$key]; // the header (String, not index)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a little math to set the right keys.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $values[(int) $key / 3][$headers[$key % 3]] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a combination of [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) , and [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$headers = array("Name","Phone","E-Mail");
$data = array("Bob", "Phone1", "E-Mail1", "Mike", "Phone2", "Email2", "Jim",  "Phone3", "E-Mail3");

$result = array_map( function ( $chunk ) use ( $headers ) { 
  return array_combine( $headers, $chunk );
}, array_chunk( $data, count( $headers ) ) );
```

Result:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [Name] => Bob 
            [Phone] => Phone1 
            [E-Mail] => E-Mail1 
        ) 

    [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [Name] => Mike 
            [Phone] => Phone2 
            [E-Mail] => Email2 
        ) 

    [2] => Array 
        ( 
            [Name] => Jim 
            [Phone] => Phone3 
            [E-Mail] => E-Mail3 
        ) 

)
```